# Angular v6 - Lazy Loaded Routes Not Loading

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

**UPDATE**

It seems that this should not have been working in Angular 5 - but for some reason it was. The `loadChildren` value needs to be a plain string, or a [LoadChildrenCallback](https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren). I've tried the callback - with Observable - but as many issues point out this invariably breaks lazy loading. Just going with the plain string option

---

After updating to Angular 6, with the CLI v6.
I have a lazy loaded route set up as follows

```
import { BLOG_CONFIG } from './BLOG_CONFIG';

const blogPath = BLOG_CONFIG.blogPath;
const categoriesPath = BLOG_CONFIG.categoriesPath;
const categoriesModulePath = BLOG_CONFIG.categoriesModulePath;

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: `${blogPath}/${categoriesPath}`, loadChildren: categoriesModulePath }
];
```

Blog Config is:

```
export const BLOG_CONFIG = {
  blogPath: 'blog',
  postsPath: 'post',
  categoriesPath: 'categories',
  categoriesModulePath: './modules/categories/categories.module#CategoriesModule',
}
```

When I navigate to the `blog/categories` route, there is a console error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./modules/categories/categories.module.ngfactory".
Error: Cannot find module "./modules/categories/categories.module.ngfactory".
```

If I change the route so the `loadChildren` **uses the string directly it works ok!**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: `${blogPath}/${categoriesPath}`, loadChildren: './modules/categories/categories.module#CategoriesModule' }
];
```

**This was not happening in Angular 5. Am I missing something simple here!?**

Note: when it works with the string I get the CLI output for `ng serve --aot`

```
chunk {modules-categories-categories-module-ngfactory} modules-categories-categories-module-ngfactory.js, modules-categories-categories-module-ngfactory.js.map (modules-categories-categories-module-ngfactory) 70.5 kB  [rendered]
```

I'm thinking it's a `webpack` problem with reading the BlogConfig object maybe, but not sure

Comment: You declare a `const` named `categoriesModulePath`, but you do not use it in the `routes` array. I don't think that will fix the issue, but something to note. It would be interesting if it did fix it.

Comment: ` './modules/categories/categories.module#CategoriesModule',` looks like this path is wrong. End of story ;)

Comment: @R.Richards actually it can fix the issue.

Comment: You can always create a plunker or stackblitz (i preffere 2nd option)

Comment: @R.Richards I have used both the const and the config directly - neither work. The route is correct, as if I use it directly as a string then the chunk builds. Otherwise there are no errors during build, but the chunk is not created

Comment: Are you lazy loading this module in more that one place? I guess, what I am wondering, is if using a config for this is really necessary. I like the idea. But I wonder if it is worth it. Maybe try using string interpolation there, like this: `loadChildren: `${categoriesModulePath}``.

Comment: So, it seems that it should not have been working in Angular 5 either, but for some reason it did. The value for `loadChildren` needs to be a string, or a `LoadChildrenCallback` e.g. Promise/Observable - but these invariably break lazy loading (lots of issue logged). So, gonna use a plain old string https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
loadChildren: BLOG_CONFIG.categoriesModulePath
```

Comment: I tried that and using that value as a const. Just strange that it works in v5. The chunk is simply not generated - will have to see if I can reproduce on StackBlitz. I didn't downvote that btw

Comment: It is possible as well as this is a bug, and maybe you will have to file it to angular/webpack github ;)